# ¿Click sostenido jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas, ando bloqueado para realizar una acción con jQuery.

Tengo esto:

```
<div>
  <p>
    Password: <span id="passwordServer">*********</span> 
    <b><i id="togglePasswordServer" class="unhide icon"></i></b>
  </p>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var passwordServer = "123456";
    $("#passwordServer").text(passwordServer);
  });
</script>
```

Básicamente lo que quiero hacer es el *password* aparezca oculto mientras no se tenga oprimido en en la etiqueta y he estado investigando y se muestra que con la función `longclick` pero toca con plugin externo a *jQuery*.

El *password* que esta almacenado en la variable `passwordServer` no se vería hasta que se mantenga oprimido el `i` con `id="togglePasswordServer`; si se deja de oprimir vuelve a mostrar los `*****`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si no te he entendido mal lo que pretendes hacer es algo así:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var passwordServer = "123456";
  
  function hide() { 
    $('#passwordServer').text(Array(passwordServer.length + 1).join('*'));
  }
  
  function show() {
    $('#passwordServer').text(passwordServer);
  }
  
  $('#togglePasswordServer')
    .on('mousedown', show)
    .on('mouseup', hide)
    .on('mouseout', hide);
  
  hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>
    Password: <span id="passwordServer"></span>
    <b><i id="togglePasswordServer" class="unhide icon">icon</i></b>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias Buen Hombre

Comment: En adicional como hago para que el punto también cambie cuando se esta encima de icon ---Actualización: Olvídalo amigo :)

Answer (score 7):

Puedes utilizar los eventos `mousedown` y `mouseup` para detectar cuando haces click en el elemento en cuestión y cuando quitas el ratón del mismo.

En este caso utilizo un `input` en vez de un `span` para hacerlo más sencillo.

Ejemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#password').mousedown(function(){
    $(this).attr("type","text");              
  }).mouseup(function(){
    $(this).attr("type","password");            
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="password" type="password" value="Esto es una contraseña">
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto te podria ayudar, suerte...

Ejemplo:

```
<div>
  <p>
    Password: <span id="passwordServer">*********</span>
    <br>
    <b><i id="togglePasswordServer" class="unhide icon" style="cursor: pointer; ">Mostrar Clave</i></b>
    </p>
</div>

$(function(){
    var passwordServer = "123456";

    $('.unhide').mousedown(function(){
        $('#passwordServer').text(passwordServer);
    }).mouseup(function(){
        $('#passwordServer').text('***************');
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $('#passwordServer').text('***************');
    });
});
```